# as for a flex http request, how to set the header attributes when special characters are contained

Tags: apache-flex, http, actionscript

My task is to call some api in flex, and I use HTTPService to send a request to the server. It must be authenticated if I want to retrieve any data from the server. The authentication information are put in the headers of a request. Now the problem is if the attribute contains some special characters (a colon for instance), then the request won't work, which means the authentication failed. Actually this attribute is then neglected. Is some encoding needed when setting those attributes?

```
// this attribute will be negelected, for colons are contained in it.
http.headers["X-wsse"] = "Created=\"2013-01-02T11:29:13+01:00\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Colon isn't special in HTTP header field values.

You may want to check the documentation of "X-wsse" (whatever that is).